# String move first word to end of string

Tags: c++, string, append

I have looked up many examples of how to do this but none seem to work properly.
I have a file with names like such

```
  Fen' Harel, Solas
  De Fer, Vivienne 
  Rainier, Thom
  Blackwall, Gordon
  Nightingale, Leliana
```

There is more names but this is just an example
the names are in the format LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
I want to output them in the order FIRSTNAME LASTNAME //with no ","

```
// before this is the functions getting the data from the string 
//and putting it into arrays, and they all work

//This function loops the output for each set of names in the file
void output(string n[], int s){

for(int i = 0; i<s;i++){
    formatName(n[i]);
cout<<endl;
}
}
// This function adjusts the format of the names
void formatName(string names){
    string name ="";
    int size = 0;
    size = names.find(",");
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    name = moveFirstToLast(names);  
    }

    cout<<name; 
}
//This function is what should move the first name to the last name but is not working
string moveFirstToLast(string name){
    name = name + name[0];
    name.erase(0,1);
    return name;
}
```

When the program is run the following is displayed

```
 en Harel, Solas
De Fer, Vivienne 
 ainier, Thom
 lackwall, Gordon
 ightingale, Leliana
```

so there is a problem where the first name is not being appended to the name and is also doe snot appear to be looping and for some reason the second name is being skipped entirely

Comment: So `formatName` takes name**s**? No, it doesn't. It takes **one** name and has to do `name = moveFirstToLast(name);` repeatedly. The first two lines of the function are useless (when you rename the parameter and do `size_t size = names.find(",");`), like you should have.

Comment: An algorithm to do this is: 1. Reverse entire array. 2. Locate comma. 3. Reverse everything from string start to (but not including) the space before the comma. 4. Reverse everything from (and including) the comma to end of string. 5. Remove the comma (the last character in the string). Done, and no intermediate buffer required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substr` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) method once you use `find` to get the position of the ',' in the string. From there, you can rebuild the string by swapping the substring from 0..(position of comma) and (position of comma + 1)..(length of string - 1).